# Java8 Lists. Call a void function

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have following piece of code in my controller, from 1st list I get all the users and then I iterate to send them an email. Somehow in the function `sendEmail()` I am obliged to return an object, but I don't need to return anything.

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

menuPriceSummaryService.findAll()
    .stream()
    .map (mps -> checkPreferences(mps))
    .iterator()
    .forEachRemaining(users::addAll);

users
    .stream()
    .map (o -> sendEmail(o))
    .iterator();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`map` is not the correct operation in your scenario. `forEach` is, since it's a terminal operation (so you don't need any call after it) and it only consumes the `Stream` elements without having to return anything:

```
users.stream().forEach (o -> sendEmail(o));
```

Or you can directly call `forEach` on the `List`, as Aris suggested:

```
users.forEach (o -> sendEmail(o));
```

Comment: Actually even the .stream() is also unnecessary. He can very well do `users.forEach(this::sendEmail)`, provided that the sendMail() method resides within the service in question.

Comment: @Aris that's true

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you are using iterators here.

```
List<User> users = menuPriceSummaryService.findAll()
            .stream()
            .flatMap (mps -> checkPreferences(mps).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then just use `List.forEach`:

```
users.forEach(o -> sendEmail(o));
```

If you don't require the `users` list afterwards, you can replace the `collect` above with `forEach` (and remove the variable declaration, of course).